# write the result set into .csv file using java

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to write the result set into .csv file using java, for that I wrote code, this created a .csv file but the result set data is not coming into .csv file, I want what ever the result set printed in console should be write in to .csv file. Could some one help me out of this.

```java
public class JdbcEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/print_list", "root", "7012");

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();) {

            String strSelect = "select * from employee";
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            //int colCount = 0;
            while (rset.next()) {
                String userName = rset.getString("username");
                String firstName = rset.getString("firstname");
                String lastName = rset.getString("lastname");
                String emailId = rset.getString("emailid");
                String address = rset.getString("address");
                System.out.println(userName + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName);

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();
        File csvFile = new File("employee.csv");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(csvFile);

        for (Employee employeeList : employee) {
            out.println(((Employee) employeeList).getLastName());
        }
        out.close();
    }

    private String getFirstName() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), and describe the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: Your list employee is always empty. You create the empty list after iterating over the result set and nowhere do you insert an element. And why is the list called employee and one element employeeList? This is quite confusing.

Comment: You can use https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/103-resultset-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

Just print output to csv within while loop.

Note that you must include `ResultSet` and `PrintWriter` into `try-with-resources` statement as well to ensure the resource is closed after the program is finished.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File csvFile = new File("employee.csv");
    String strSelect = "select * from employee";
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/print_list", "root", "7012");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(csvFile)) {
        //int colCount = 0;
        while (rset.next()) {
            String userName = rset.getString("username");
            String firstName = rset.getString("firstname");
            String lastName = rset.getString("lastname");
            String emailId = rset.getString("emailid");
            String address = rset.getString("address");
            out.println(userName + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName + "," + emailId + "," + address);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Apache Commons CSV library.

Examples can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv